# duplicating results between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a transaction table that adds a record for each time a customer changes status and I'm trying to write a procedure in t-sql in SQL 2008 Management Studio that will find the last status a customer had for each day which I can do.

The problem I'm having is filling in the last status for each day that there was not a change in status.Here is an example of the data I'm trying to fill in. I need AB to be the status for each date between the two status dates.

```
Customer Number Status  Status Date
XXXXXX123       AB          2/15/2013


XXXXXX123       AC          2/24/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`Select status from (select * from table where date < enddate order by date desc limit 1)`

This will find the row in the table with the most recent date that is still under the ending date, and then you can grab its status.

Comment: Thank you.Yes that will work, but I'm trying to fill the dates between status dates with the last status on 2/15/2013. So AB would be the status for dates 2/16-2/23 even though I haven't had a change in status. I need this so I can count how many records are in what status on any date.

Comment: @MarcusWilliams So do that kind of query as an `update` statement, for every date where there is no status change for that date?